# Set iPhone ringtone for filtered email messages

Tags: iphone, email, exchange-activesync, ringtones

Is there a way on the iPhone that a certain subset of incoming emails (coming through Exchange) will ring a specific ringtone (a real one, not just a beep)?

In the Blackberry world, you would set an email filter that marks these emails as priority 1, and have a different ringtone for priority 1 messages. I'm hoping to accomplish the same thing with an iPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a native way to do this, but you could set up server side rules (via Outlook Web Access, server side so they always process) to forward particular messages to a notification service, such as Boxcar (www.boxcar.io), then configure individual sounds using their iOS app.

Here's a page that shows how to setup forwarding rules in OWA (chosen randomly via Google):
http://programs.cocc.edu/OWA/FW/default.aspx

One catch with this is that, as far as I can tell, the Rules functionality is only available in Internet Explorer, at least with Exchange 2007. I tried this in Chrome and Safari on my Mac at home and the option isn't available.  I've heard non-IE browser support is better for Exchange 2010. If you don't have access to IE, Google a bit to see if you can find any tips for using IE 8 or 9 on OS X. I found one, but I'm not exactly sure of it's legitimacy, so I chose not to post a link.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the idea. I'm not worried about the IE thing - access to a Windows machine is not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

How about https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mailtones-email-alerts-sounds/id329330329?mt=8

Has anyone used this before?